# What language choose for implementing server with huge load?

Tags: programming-languages

We have SMS server, written on Delphi. 
This server receives information from its clients (user id, text of sms) and sends sms through SMS Gateway. This server works OK with minimal amount of clients, but there can be situation, where 1 million clients will appear and server will simply crash. So, we decided to rewrite our Server. We want to create clusters (network of computers) that will somehow serve users. 
We considered 2 languages: C or Java. C - because we have programmers on C, Java - because we think it would be easy to implement server on it... :)  What can you suggest?

Comment: On a different note: Would plugging a round-robin load balancer in front and simply running your existing server software on maybe 3-4 servers not maybe be cheaper? If that doesn't work, I would favour C, because I think it's exactly the right tool for the job here (simple operation, fixed size data, must run fast, ... cries for C).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest C because you already have the in-house expertise for it. It sounds like you have C people who already know how to build servers, so just make use of that! I can't think of a compelling reason to go with Java if your workplace is unfamiliar with it and can get the job done with different tools.

---

Of course, if your dev team is only one guy who has never written a server than you are *almost* starting from scratch. Are you hiring new developers (or contractors) to build this, or retraining your one guy? If you're hiring new, I'd maybe suggest Java as I think it might be easier to implement something like this, but that could be because I'm not as aware of the C ecosystem of libraries that would this easier as I am with the Java ecosystem.

Comment: No, these C people in fact one person. Sorry for misleading. And this person did not write Servers before.

Comment: we have team of developers, who knows C#, Delphi. So three things will happen: or we will hire Java developers, or we will study our guys Java or we will write Server on C#. But we do not want to do it. Because we will be platform-dependent. And we want our server to be multiplatform.

Comment: Than Java or C might be a better choice than C#, though with Mono you can run C# on non-Windows systems. Just make sure the libraries you use are also available in other environments.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer Java. Firstly because it has good libraries and resources which are useful for servers. Secondly, because C is a headache.

Comment: I prefer Java, because I think on Java we can implement Server quicker, with less memory leaks... But I do not know, how Java is good for 1 million users. And can we divide load between computers...